# iframe and css compatibility

Tags: html, css, iframe, joomla

I need some compatibility help.  My website looks different in browsers.  Chrome/firefox, etc. looks right but IE is messed up.  Take a look at: http://southwestarkansasradio.com/joomla

I'm using Joomla 2.5.  The search box is moved to the left and my on air box script does not work in IE.  Code is below, can you help?   thanks.

```
<table border="0">
<tr>
<th>
<center><img style="float: left;"
src="http://www.southwestarkansasradio.com/images/onair995.jpg" alt="" height="35"     
width="316" /><br><img 
src="http://www.southwestarkansasradio.com/images/playerbackground.jpg" width="316" 
height="216" alt="" border="1"><div id="now playing" style="position: absolute; top: 
60px; left: 20px;>

<!--[if IE]>

<iframe src="http://www.southwestarkansasradio.com/NowPlaying.html" name="nowplaying"   
style="height:216px" "width:316px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" border="none" 
allowtransparency="true" valign="top" ></iframe>

<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]>-->

<iframe src="http://www.southwestarkansasradio.com/NowPlaying.html" name="nowplaying" 
style="height:216px" "width:316px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" border="none" 
valign="top" ></iframe>

<!--<![endif]-->

</div></center>
</th></tr></table></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That html is really hard to read for such a small piece of code. Using indentation would make it easier for you to spot mistakes. There were a number of things wrong:

- the opening div was missing from the snippet
- One of the divs "now playing" has a space in the id. One cannot have spaces in HTML IDs.
- you should have a trailing slash in the br tag
- you haven't closed the css style in the nowplaying div, i.e. you forgot the closing apostophe. This would cause problems.
- iframe does not have a valign property
- the height and width in the iframes are badly formed
- iframes do not have a border property

Something like the following should serve better but without being able to debug on your server it's guesswork. Anyway, as said I've kept it pretty much to your structure and fixed fixed the obvious stuff but there will probably still be some issues when you try it on the site but it will get you closer. I certainly wouldn't do it this way however.

The w3c validator is a handy tool.

```
<div>
    <table border="0"> 
        <tr> 
            <th> 
                <center>
                    <img style="float: left;" src="http://www.southwestarkansasradio.com/images/onair995.jpg" alt="" height="35" width="316" />
                    <br/>
                    <img src="http://www.southwestarkansasradio.com/images/playerbackground.jpg" width="316" height="216" alt="" border="1">

                    <div id="nowplaying" style="position: absolute; top: 60px; left: 20px;"> 
                        <!--[if IE]>
                            <iframe src="http://www.southwestarkansasradio.com/NowPlaying.html" name="nowplaying" height="216px" width="316px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" ></iframe> 
                        <![endif]-->

                        <!--[if !IE]>--> 
                            <iframe src="http://www.southwestarkansasradio.com/NowPlaying.html" name="nowplaying" height="216px" width="316px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe> 
                        <!--<![endif]--> 
                    </div>
                </center>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is just a hack but to move the search box in IE8 and IE9 (haven't tried IE7) add the following to the head section of your template's index.php. It's just "pushing" the search box over.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
div.topmenu
{
    width: 250px !important;
}

div.search
{
    margin-left: 30px !important;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i should have thought of using a validator.

Comment: thanks again, it worked!   Now my only question is how to get that darn search box to move into it's correct place on internet explorer.  I know the answer lies somewhere in the css but i just can't find the correct number to change.  If your interested, can u check?   http://southwestarkansasradio.com/joomla/templates/justbusiness-fjt/css/styles.css
thanks

Comment: heya. Have updated the answer above. If it works you should accept or vote for the answer. Not the most elegant of fixes but worked for me in IE8 and IE9 when I applied the styles directly to the end of style2.css (however you only want those styles implemented for IE, hence putting the conditional comment in the index file.